# Australian PTSD dependant on UK based partner - can I return?

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, australian-citizens, ireland, health

I am an Australian who finished their Youth Mobility Visa in July 2016. I was diagnosed with PTSD 5 years ago.

My partner is still in the UK proceeding with residency application - he has the right to work and awaiting the residency application outcome.

I exited UK in compliance with law and on the specified date. I am in Republic of Ireland.I want to return to be with my partner due to health issues (diagnosed in UK), and continuing mental health issues.

I have private health insurance until the end of 2016. I would be a private paying client for health issues.

I cannot safely lean on my family, who are documented in therapists letter as physically and emotionally abusive.

Would I be able to get a tourist visa based on those grounds? To undertake private therapy and private medical treatment for health issue?

I literally have noone else to rely or lean on.

I cannot go back to Australia there is noone who can support me.

Comment: You would not be able to get a tourist visa if your visit is premised on the presence of a partner in the UK. With such a premise, you would need a family-based visa. If you do not premise your visit on the partner, but on the medical care, you might be able to enter as a "standard visitor." As an Australian, you may be able to do that without a visa.

Comment: So coming from Ireland, do I go to British Immigration and declare myself? To get a stamp?

Comment: I believe there are some related questions on [Travel.SE].